# MySQL PHP: PDO connection not working when getting credentials from file()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've already searched for an answer to this questions, but all that I found didn't work for me. I've a problem with the pdo connection in php.

When I enter the mysql datas directly into the pdo statement, it works properly. But when I use variables instead, it doesn't. I already looked up how to include variables into a pdo statement, but it didn't work.

This is the code, when it works:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'Database';

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

And here is the code, when it doesn't work:

```
$file = "mysqldatas.txt";
$lines = file($file);
$host = $lines[1];
$username = $lines[2];
$password = $lines[3];
$dbname = $lines[4];

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

As you can see, I try to read the datas from a text file the second time. But I don't see where the difference between 'localhost', and $lines[1] is, because when I echo the $lines[1], the output is localhost, as it should be.

Please help me guys, this is really annoying. It would be great, if you could also explain why it makes a difference between directly entering the hostname, or using a variable, that holds the hostname (as I said, I used echo, and it said localhost).

Thank you for your help guys!
Bye.

Comment: try doing print_r($lines) and tell us the result

Comment: Can you try printing the values var_dump instead of echo to see what it shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue is that the `file()` will also get newlines with each line, unless the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is used (or some sort of `trim()` function). So you'll need to use

```
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

instead. From the manual of `file()`, it tells us that

> Note:
>   Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.

`trim()` is also a possibility instead of this flag.

---

There's a few other, different possibilities to separate credentials and connections, the most common one is to either use a file `connection.php` which creates the object, where you just include that, and use that wherever you need a connection, or creating your own `.ini` file with the credentials, and getting it via `parse_ini_file()`.

connection.php

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'Database';

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Other files

```
require "path/to/connection.php";
$con->prepare(...);
```

---

Then there's usage of `.ini` files. You can create a `config.ini` file, and get the values from `parse_ini_file()`

config.ini

```
host = localhost
dbname = Database
user = root
password = password
type = mysql
```

Connection

```
$config = parse_ini_file("config.ini");
$con = new PDO($config['type'].":host=".$config['host'].";dbname=".$config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
```

## References

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php or  http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer! It worked perfectly fine with creating the ini file and reading the login datas from it!

Answer (score 1):

pretty sure you are getting newlines when you use the file function. try this:

```
$file = "mysqldatas.txt";
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$host = $lines[1];
$username = $lines[2];
$password = $lines[3];
$dbname = $lines[4];

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Comment: `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` may not be needed, and may even cause problems

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php :

> Return Values ¶
>
> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the newline still attached**. Upon failure, file() returns FALSE.